# Servlet JDBC Inserts old values too

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I have an web application with an Ajax request to a Servlet. When an user clicks a button it sends an ajax request to the servlet which will have to add a list of records to the DB.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String username = session.getAttribute("username").toString();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
        String parameter = request.getParameter("items");
        out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(testVariable);
        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        insertRecords(parameter, username);

    }


private void insertRecords(String records, String user){
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>(); //This is the list of records i want to add into DB
        if(records.contains("-")){
            String[] split = records.split("-");
            for(String item : split){
                items.add(item);
            }
        }
        else{
            items.add(records);
        }
        try {
            out.println("LIST: " + items); //This is just for test
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO records(productName, productCategory, user) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            for(String record : items) {
                String parent = getParentForSubproduct(record);// This method does two selects into DB without closing the connection afterwards.
                stmt.setString(1, record);
                if(parent.equals(""))
                    stmt.setString(2, record);
                else
                    stmt.setString(2, parent);
                stmt.setString(3, user);
                out.println("RECORD: " + record);//This is just for test
                testVariable++;
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }

                if(stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
                conn.close();


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(out);
        }
        out.println("TIMES EXECUTED LOOP:  " + testVariable);
    }
```

The problem is that after doing more than one insert (after calling "insertRecords" more than one time) it inserts ALL of the already inserted values + the new one . Every time. I have no idea how to resolve this. I wasted one day on this.

//EDIT: I just tested out and the loop is execute more times. After the first button(first servlet call) the output would be ""TIMES EXECUTED LOOP:  1". After the second one, the output would be: "TIMES EXECUTED LOOP:  3".

Comment: Could you try to print the content of `parameter` ?

Comment: Yes, i did that too and it prints the right values. The ones i want to add

Comment: I edited my posted. Maybe it would help

Comment: GET should not making changes in state. Can be cached, executed many times etc

Comment: So what would a solution be ?

Comment: @aNNgeL0 please add ur html/jsp and ajaz code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JacekCz mentions HTTP GET has some problems.

Here I guess that on the page something like the following (not the following) is used

```
<a href="#" onclick="...">
```

This could do a **page reload twice** (the href and in javascript). Other variants are possible. Also an HTML element could do a GET of almost the same URL and effect the same servlet.

With Ajax something similar could happen. The usage of a dash-separated list points to JavaScript. A bit of logging will find the cause - I hope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to do more logs :(

Comment: I managed to solve the issue thanks to your "This could do a page reload twice" tip. Will post the answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JoopEggen tips i managed to solve the problem. There was a coding error with my Ajax. Here is the code i used:

The action on the button was to call a method where it had the ajax code for the servlet too inside:

```
$(function(){
            var list = translateArrayToString(array);
            $('#finish').on('click', function (event) {
                alert("test");
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'myServlet',
                    async: false,
                    data : {
                        items : list
                    },
                    success : function(responseText) {
                        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
```

So as you can see it had another on click event so that is why it was called more than one time. Here is the working Ajax code:

```
$(function(){
            var list = translateArrayToString(array);
            alert("test");
            $.ajax({
                url : 'MyServlet',
                async: false,
                data : {
                    items : list
                },
                success : function(responseText) {
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
                }
            });

        });
```